# Android studio, build errors during flutter build on linux

Tags: linux, flutter, android-studio, dart, desktop-application

While trying to build the default flutter script that comes along with android studio as a linux desktop application, the following error message is being encountered:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
Building Linux application...
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

Your efforts in helping me to troubleshoot the problem will be worth a lot.

Checked the installation of cmake on my device, cmake was running as expected.
Not sure why the error is being encountered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.